# Do add_roles and remove_roles "hit" the discord service if they wouldn't result in a change?

Tags: python, roles, discord.py

Question about [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) and [`Member.remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles) on the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.

If I just...

```py
import discord, asyncio

guild = discord.Guild()

for member in guild.members
   ...
   await member.add_roles(desiredRole)
```

But 80 of the 100 members have the `desiredRole`, does my bot send 100 commands to discord or 20?

In other words, does [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) check a member's roles and decide if to send the command, or do I need to do that on my own in order not to run into limit issues if I cycle through 1000 users on 200 servers each, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The underlying implementation is actually to create a list of the roles you should have and send that to Discord via `member.edit`. [You can see the code for `add_roles` here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/b77af199392209017e59eff366b46354fa210f64/discord/member.py#L605).

You can always perform this check locally yourself by looking at `member.roles`

Comment: Ok, so I read the code, and it looks like I would indeed be sending 1 request to discord per user whether they have the desiredRole or not.  Thank you.